# Knowing a geography coordinate nearby

Tags: math

I am using geographic coordinates (latitude, longitude). I have the coordinates of each corner of a wall.

I would like to know the coordinates of a point 10cm to the right of the lower left.  I am not sure if it is possible.

Thanks.

Comment: For future reference: better ask this sort of thing on [SE Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/). Stack overflow is more for specific programming questions; on SE Math, you'll have the "right crowd" looking at your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get coordinate from other two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516598/get-coordinate-from-other-two)

Answer (score 3):

### Simple method

Since latitude and longitude are a system of coordinates on a non-Euclidian surface (spherical 2-space), they are pretty awkward to work with directly.

I'd suggest the following. Convert your two coordinates to 3D Cartesian vectors:

```
z = R * sin(latitude);
Rcoslat = R * cos(latitude);
x = Rcoslat * cos(longitude);
y = Rcoslat * sin(longitude);
```

with `R = 6378 km` the (mean) radius of the Earth. Note that most trig functions in most computer languages take their argument in **radians**, so you'll have to multiply any degrees you have by `pi/180` before taking their `sin()` or `cos()`.

Doing this for both coordinates of a side of the wall gives you two vectors

```
v1 = (x1 y1 z1)
v2 = (x2 y2 z2)
```

The difference between these vectors will give you the proper direction to go in:

```
v3 = v1-v2  (if v1 is your leftmost coordinate)
v3 = v2-v1  (if v2 is your leftmost coordinate)
```

The length of `v3` is the width of your wall. Extend it by 10cm to get a new vector:

```
L  = sqrt( v3x*v3x + v3y*v3y + v3z*v3z )  (width of the wall)
v4 = v3/L * (L+10cm) = v3 * (1 + 10cm/L)
```

Note that you'll have to do some unit juggling there, since if you take `R` in kilometers, `L` will be in kilometers, too.

Now that you have the new vector, you can convert it back to latitude/longitude:

```
hypotxy   = hypot( v4x, v4y)
latitude  = atan2( v4z, hypotxy )
longitude = atan2( v4y, v4x )
```

Where `atan2` is the four-quadrant arctangent, and `hypot(a,b)` is just a fairly standard way to compute `sqrt(a*a+b*b)` with a greatly reduced risk of numerical over/underflow. Note again that the output of `atan2` in most computer languages will be in **radians**, so if you want your latitude/longitude in degrees, you'll have to multiply the outcome by `180/pi`.

### Any more accurate method

The method above makes a few errors due to some simplifications that are hardly noticeable on small scales (like your ordinary everyday wall). But of your wall is actually the Great Wall of China, then you'll find that these errors become pretty unacceptable.

The errors made are due to these assumptions:

1. Latitude and longitude are coordinates on a sphere. Usually, they're not. If they come from a GPS receiver of some quality, they describe coordinates on the [reference ellipsoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_ellipsoid) of the Earth. The conversion between *these* coordinates and a Cartesian vector is slightly more involved.
2. The difference vector `v3` is just that, a vector. A vector is a straight line segment, while the actual line connecting the points `v1` and `v2` is slightly curved (because the Earth is not flat). Extending `v3` to find `v4` will therefore introduce an error. You'll actually have to extend the *curved* line. Again, this can be done simply (by assuming the Earth is a sphere again, and using cross and dot products), or more accurately (by extending the line on the Earth's reference ellipsoid).

These corrections are pretty specific and can get very long and very ugly, so I'll leave it at this. I think the "simple method" above suffices for your need anyway.

Nevertheless, if you ever need to do it with more accuracy: If you're smart, you'll use some existing Geo software library for it. If you're smarter, you'll look up all the formulas and relevant information and make the implementation yourself, discover that your implementation has errors and side effects, correct them and learn from this again :)

Comment: Hello, Thank you very much for you answer. The problem is that it is a  wall of a building. So, the coordinate for a side will be the same, only with a different altitude, right?

Comment: @user1685439: You're saying you have only the coordinates of a lower and upper corner of the building, in other words, a vertical line? In that case, there's too little information to know what "to the right" means...you need to know the orientation of the wall's horizontal -- i.e., does it run due West? NorthNorthEast? You can't solve the problem if you don't have this information. If you have control over where you get the coordinates from, I'd suggest you also get a coordinate from the lower corner on the other side of the lower corner you already have.

Comment: I have two coordinates (waypoints -> latitude, longitude and altitude) . One of the lower left corner and another of the lower right corner. It is easy to know what is the altitude in the top of the wall, it is only plus the wall's height to my current altitude. so it is not a problem. So my idea, it is make a Canvas in my website, and when i draw for example in the position (X,Y) , Y would be the altitude, but i need to move to the right or and the left with the right coordenate.

Comment: So, if i know to move on the right or left, i will use the Y coordinates in the Canvas to set the altitude